# How to fetch data from Firebase Firestore to card views on html

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, google-cloud-firestore

I am new to web development and recently, I am making a music streaming website. I want to get data from firestore to card views.
Let me explain my issue using an example,
I have a collection named Musicians in firestore.

This is an example of my data structure,

```
Musicians---
            Random_ID_01--
                          Artist_name:"Isuru"
                          Image_URL:"url"
            Random_ID_02--
                          Artist_name:"Jonny"
                          Image_URL:"url"
            Random_ID_03--
                          Artist_name:"Alex"
                          Image_URL:"url"
```

I want to paginate these data like below,

```
db.collection("Musicians").orderBy("Artist_name").startAt(first_letter_of_name).endAt(first_letter_of_name +'\uf88ff');
```

I am using Boostrap alphabetical pagination bar to get the clicked value.
When the user clicks button "A" I want to fetch all the artists which the first letter starting  "A".
I tried using many methods like cloneNode(true) but it wasn't like what I wanted because it was adding all the data to the same page while old data remaining.
The way I want to display artist data is when the user clicks button "A" Alex's card should appear on the page and when the user clicks button "J" Jonny's card should appear on the page but Alex's card should not be there.

I would be greatly appreciated, If you can explain to me using js or Jquery source codes

Comment: If you already achieved retrieving the documents whose `Artist_name` starts with a particular letter the only step remaining would be to purge the application/page state whenever another button letter is clicked, the exact steps will depend on how your state and rendering logic is implemented.

Comment: @Happy-Monad, yeah I tried it using cloneNode for the template , but it always adding new data while old data remaining. I'm new to web development, therefore, I don't have an idea about this. I am still trying.